# Handling Customer Card Updates with Stripe Payment Processor

Tags: recurring-contributions, stripe

Does the Stripe Payment Processor handle customer credit card updates for recurring contributions? And does it depend on whether I'm using Civicrm 4.6 or 4.7?

I see this page from Stripe:
https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/updating-customer-cards

Not sure if it is implemented in the Stripe extension.

Comment: Are you able to answer your own question perhaps? I suspect the answer is 'not possible'.

Comment: I'm also very interested in this.  Can someone from drastikbydesign please comment?  I know I can update a donor's credit card info directly in Stripe, but how to securely get that info from my donor?  What page can I send them to?  And sadly I'm not a programmer...

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet implemented. See: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/64

Answer (score 0):

https://civicrm.org/extensions/stripe-payment-processor states

> It handles regular contributions as well as recurring through Stripe's subscription/plan feature.

and

CiviCRM Compatibility = CiviCRM 4.5, CiviCRM 4.6, CiviCRM 4.7

Comment: I'm asking about card updates.  For example if a customer wants to change the credit card he uses for an existing subscription.

Comment: my apologies - speed reading fail.